# Perl regex multiple characters

Tags: regex, perl, file

What do I have to do if I want the program to look if the string has those characters.
Let's make an example:
I want to dispense with those characters : `'*',':','&','=',...`
And the code I use is:

```
if(!($line =~ /(\*|\:|\&)/)){
```

But when I try to compile it gives an error:

```
Unknown verb pattern '|a' in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(*|,|&|:) <-- HERE / 
at busquedas.pl line 10.
```

Error for those who don't believe me ;)
Thanks.[image]

Comment: Cannot replicate that error. And it does not go with that regex, as mentioned in the error itself. The regex it belongs to is at line 10 and starts like it says: `/(*|a)`

Comment: You can't just swap out parts of the error message willy nilly. You need to cut and paste the *exact* error message, and make sure it belongs to *exactly* the line of code you show.

Comment: Ok, take a look at the photo @TLP

Comment: *"Don't believe me"* ??? It's not that we don't believe, it's you that you don't understand what you're being told.

Comment: That's a completely different error than the one in your question. For one thing, there's no `|a` in the regex in your question. For another thing, you have escaped the asterix `\*` in both your regex and your error. It is impossible to answer your question if you change the small details like this.

Comment: @TLP Yes It's my fault! but I didn't realise that was the previous version. Sorry

Comment: Wow... at least two, maybe three separate error messages all mangled together; and none of them actually match the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for single characters, you could just use a [character class](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Using-character-classes) like this:

```
if(!($line =~ /[*:&=]/)){
```

Comment: it gives me that error: Useless use of concatenation (.) or string in void context at busquedas.pl line 12.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting the error. The only way how to get it is to follow the opening parenthesis immediately with a `*`.

```
$ perl -we 'if(!($line =~ /(\*|\:|\&)/)){}' 
Name "main::line" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $line in pattern match (m//) at -e line 1.
$ perl -we 'if(!($line =~ /(*|\:|\&)/)){}' 
Unknown verb pattern '|\' in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(*|\:|\&) <-- HERE / at -e line 1.
```

How do you run the code? Have you really pasted the line that produces the error?

`splain` says:

```
Unknown verb pattern '' in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(*) <-- HERE / at -e
    line 1 (#1)
(F) You either made a typo or have incorrectly put a * quantifier
after an open brace in your pattern.  Check the pattern and review
perlre for details on legal verb patterns.
```